# String escape not working

Tags: c#

I'm new at this, but i'm having a problem with this escape sequece:

```
string e = "Joe said \"Hello\" to me";
```

should be returning =

```
 "Joe said "Hello" to me"
```

but instead returns the exact literal:

```
"Joe said \"Hello\" to me"
```

I don't know why this is not working properly.

Comment: Most likely dup of many "when I look at string in debugger all quotes are escaped with `\`" question...

Comment: If you're printing that is the Immediate window, then that's what'll happen: it includes escape characters where code would need them. Or are you printing to the console or filling a text box or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use :

**Regular String Literal**

```
"Joe said \"Hello\" to me"; //1st option
```

**Or Verbatim String Literal**

```
@"Joe said ""Hello"" to me"; //2nd option
```

Comment: 99% not going to help - likely OP looks at string in debugger :)